# Using JQuery.BlackAndWhite with a Cycle2 Carousel?

Tags: jquery-cycle2

I am putting together a Cycle2-based carousel where, essentially, every other image should be a black and white image. So, on first load it would be something like this:

IMAGE A = B&W
IMAGE B = Color
IMAGE C = B&W
IMAGE D = NOT SHOWN

Once the slideshow advances, it would be something like this:

IMAGE A = NOT SHOWN
IMAGE B = B&W
IMAGE C = Color
IMAGE D = B&W

I discovered Gianluca Guarini's [jQuery.BlackAndWhite](http://gianlucaguarini.github.io/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/) plugin which handles the black and white conversion by adding the class `.bwWrapper`. If I use the `scrollHorz` parameter, the two work nicely together, but not when using `carousel`. The carousel runs as expected, but BlackAndWhite isn't coming into play.

My code is below. The only difference between the two blocks is one is in a DIV. My guess is jQuery.BlackAndWhite runs on `(window).load` and Cycle2 `carousel` enters the picture after that?

Any thoughts on how to get these to cooperate?

```
<h3>Cycle2</h3>

<div id="slideshow">
  <a href="#" class="bwWrapper"><img src="/assets/images/img01.jpg" height="200" alt="test image"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="/assets/images/img02.jpg" height="200" alt="test image"></a>
  <a href="#" class="bwWrapper"><img src="/assets/images/img03.jpg" height="200" alt="test image"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="/assets/images/img04.jpg" height="200" alt="test image"></a>
  <a href="#" class="bwWrapper"><img src="/assets/images/img05.jpg" height="200" alt="test image"></a>
</div>

<div class="center">
    <a href=# id="prev">Prev</a> 
    <a href=# id="next">Next</a>
</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery.BlackAndWhite.js"></script>

<script>
 $(window).load(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'carousel',
        speed: '1000', 
        slides: '> a',
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#prev'
    });

   $('.bwWrapper').BlackAndWhite({
         hoverEffect: false,
         invertHoverEffect: false
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you get away with just using CSS, and not the BlackAndWhite plugin? http://jsfiddle.net/3weH2/4/

Comment: Ooo... I did not know you could do this with CSS. From the comments, it looks fairly backwards compatible. Any gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: This works perfectly! Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use CSS to make the images grayscale.  Here is a cross-browser compatible style that I've used in the past.  The first filter is for Firefox, second for IE, and third for the other modern browsers.

```
.bwWrapper img{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}
```